# Is there any way to subscribe to a thread so you get email notifications?

Tags: support, notifications

I asked a question without subscribing, but now I'm not being notified of answers. Is there any way to subscribe so that I'll get those notifications?

Comment: What do you mean by: *I asked a question without subscribing*? Do you mean that you asked from a different (unregistered) account. If you have access to your old account, you should be able to [merge the two accounts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/merge-accounts/info).

Comment: This thread suggests that you need to specifically opt in to email notifications when asking a question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/automatic-notifications

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176719/how-do-i-set-notifications-for-my-questions/176721#176721) claims that you should be able to do that anytime (not only when posting a question). But I do not see such option on my questions. (And I do not see such possibility when I click on "ask question", either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is exactly what the OP wants, but there is possibility to receive notifications from your [global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/global-inbox/info) also via email. (Assuming you did not see them on the site.)

See here:

- [Does Stack Exchange have email notification option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122320)
- [Improved Global Email Notifications](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/10/08/improved-global-email-notifications/)

The above posts are quite old - the user interface changed a bit since then. So it does not look the same as on the screenshots you see there.

Still, you should be able to find this if you go to [your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile), click on "Edit Profile & Settings" and then on "Edit Email Settings". There you can choose (among other things) whether you want to get emails about your unread inbox messages weekly/daily/every 3 hours/not at all.

---

Another way to switch on the email notifications for global inbox is using the  checkbox "Email me new responses ..." when posting a question/answer. This checkbox is only displayed if the notifications for the replies from the global inbox aren't already switched on.

See this answer on Meta Stack Exchange for a screenshot: [Email notifications on Q&A I have been involved in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310813#310818). This post on Meta Stack Exchange contains some additional details: [Receive emails for responses to posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250746#250749)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing built-in, but here's a simple way:

1. At the bottom right of every page there is a link "question feed" to the RSS feed for new activity on that question. Get that link.
2. Create an IFTTT account.
3. Use the recipe [RSS to email](https://ifttt.com/recipes/147561-rss-feed-to-email) with the aforementioned RSS link.

---

There is also [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](https://stackapps.com/q/4454), which allows you to subscribe to any questions and displays notifications within the site.