# A feature request (notification for favorited questions)

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

Why don`t I get notifications on the questions I favorited?
Like suppose, I like a question but M.S.E never notifies me whether it has been answered or commented upon.

Comment: Just to make sure: you see no highlighted questions in [your favorites tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/553439/avnish-singh?tab=favorites)? Any action on your favorites should move them to the top of that list, and also highlight the "favorites" item in your [userpage](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/553439/avnish-singh).

Comment: Related feature request: [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4867) (the posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4867) might be of interest too). Also related: [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994) (and the [linked posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6994)).

Comment: There is also this feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343). (And other questions [linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/83343) might provide further reading on related issues.)

Comment: Perhaps related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21214/442